# ext-js update params dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm building a search using ext-js.  I have an event that fires on keyup.  I want to be able to change either the URL I'm searching, or the params.  I've had luck with neither.

Here's my snippit of code:

```
Ext.get("search").on('keyup', function() {
proxy.url = '/customer/list?key=' + $('search').value;
store.load();
});
```

But, no love for me. The store loads, but the proxy.url is the old value.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want to use the `proxy.setUrl()` method instead which internally updates the connection. If changing the params is sufficient, you could also try passing the params config into the load call, e.g., `store.load({params: {...}});`